# jQuery determine mouse position within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-position

this is maybe a duplicate question but I havent seen a working solution for me

My question is how can I get the mouse position within a div?

I dont want the document as origin but the inner div (the pink content div)
so when I move the coursor to the (0|0) coordinate of the pink div I want also the (0|0) coordinates as my origin coordinates

[image]

I've setup a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B7zZ8/1/)

```
$('.content').mousemove(function(e){
    $('#xCoord').val(e.pageX);
    $('#yCoord').val(e.pageY);
});
```

this wont really work for me ... and I also tried it with

```
var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
```

but I just get an offset of 8px returned and the jQuery mousemove offset is undefined

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.pageX` returns the current mouse position referring to the window.

Try this:

```
var mouseX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
var mouseY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B7zZ8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your position is the actual position - the div position:

```
$('.content').mousemove(function(e){
        var pos=$(this).position();
        $('#xCoord').val(e.pageX-pos.left);
        $('#yCoord').val(e.pageY-pos.top);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7zZ8/3/